# How do I throw InterruptedException when using Mockito Static mocking in Junit 5?

Tags: java, mockito

**Please do not suggest PowerMock.**

I am trying to test something like the following

```
            try {
                ...
                Thread.sleep(config.getRetryInterval());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                logger.error("...");
            }
```

I try to test like...

```
 try (MockedStatic<Thread> u2 = Mockito.mockStatic(Thread.class)) {
     u2.when(() -> Thread.sleep(500)).thenThrow(new InterruptedException(""));
     assertThrows(...);
 }
```

But I get

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: It is not possible to mock static methods of java.lang.Thread to avoid interfering with class loading what leads to infinite loops

What is the proper way to handle something like this in Mockito with the new Static setup?

Comment: If you have the intention to throw ```InterruptedException```, you can stub the config.getRetryInterval() like this:

`when(config.getRetryInterval()).thenThrow(InterruptedException.class);`

Comment: If you have a static method to be mocked, you can also introduce a proxy interface that will be implemented using the static call in production code, however it tests you can pass a mock, so that you will be able to mock it. Something like interface Sleeper{ void sleep(int milliseconds); }